# Problem changing from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2

Tags: php

I have a problem with an old theme that can't be updated. My hosts (1&1) are now charging to continue using PHP 5.6 but I get the following errors when switching to PHP 7.2 and I don't know what to do. If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Warning: Declaration of mysiteDescriptionWalker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php on line 45
```

Warning: Declaration of mysiteResponsiveMenuWalker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php on line 87

Warning: Declaration of mysiteResponsiveMenuWalker::end_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php on line 87

Warning: Declaration of mysiteResponsiveMenuWalker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php on line 87

Warning: Declaration of mysiteResponsiveMenuWalker::end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php on line 87

Answer (score 1):

This can be tricky to help with without some more details.

Sounds like PHP 7 has run into some compatibility errors.

Seems that you need to look at line 87 of  /homepages/36/d129703868/htdocs/mightyoak/bhd-wp/wp-content/themes/construct/lib/classes/menu-walker.php

Is this the Construct Theme and are you running the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies everyone. The problem is the theme and there are no further updates, so I've got round it for now by stopping the errors being displayed using the following in wp config file

```
    ini_set('log_errors','On');
    ini_set('display_errors','Off');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [many incompatibilities between the versions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php).  Making sure everything, including the theme, is compatible with the latest WordPress and updated to that point should also ensure it's compatible with PHP 7.x